# Open All Variables in MATLAB Workspace at Once?

Tags: matlab, variables, spreadsheet

I am using a program that churns out a large amount of data that I want to be saved into a spreadsheet. Unfortunately, the program only outputs data into separate variables in the workspace. Currently I've only found out how to open a single variable, not all of them at once in one combined file.

I am not authorized to alter the code of this program except to change certain directories used by it. Is it possible to open all of the variables in the MATLAB workspace in one file at once, instead of individually?

Comment: I might be able to change the format of the variables and store multiple values of the same variable separately, because I have to run the program with a lot of segmentation data.The value of the variables always get overridden the next time I run the program with different data, so I might be able to make the variable a matrix.

Comment: Can you provide code on how you'd call the program, and what the names of the variables saved to the workspace are?  It's pretty poor design to run a program and rely on saving the variables to the main workspace.  The variables should really be returned from a function and allow you to place them in whatever variable names you want.

Comment: Currently I can't - this program relies on several other MATLAB files, I'm just supposed to run a main file. Not quite sure what you mean by this, each bit of data is set to a preset value: ex. saving the volume of a heart into something called heartVolume.

Comment: Which would then be saved into the workspace as heartVolume, [data value].

Comment: How do you open a single variable?

Comment: @beaker, I'm able to open it by selecting it in the workspace, it comes up as a single value in a spreadsheet.